# Why Session("userID") will be empty in some version of IE?

Tags: asp.net, session

in my site, in some versions of IE, after login and click on menu in pages, i redirect to login page....why?
in Mozilla and chrome and some versions of IE there is not problem but for example in IE 8 there is?
I dont know why?
my site has HTTPS...
thanks

Comment: Could be browser settings and whether cookies are allowed. Depends on how you are passing session ids around.

Comment: Have u tried clearing your cache and restarting IE 8?

Comment: yes.but problem not resolved.